# How to check if given url matches any existing url?

Tags: angular, typescript, url

I'm trying to do searching in my angular project and I want to check f url with value which user provides matches any existing url and return those urls.

this is fragment of my service.ts

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/clients';

  findByName(value: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}?name=${value}`);
  }
```

Is there any function which I can use? I was searching a lot but didn't find any useful answer.

Comment: All you need to do is verify is a get petition is status 200.

Comment: @DiesanRomero yes but I use it for searching and the problem is that when I type e.g. "wil" I want to get records "Will", "William" etc. and it works only when I type the exact name existing

Comment: I understand; in that case, you need a database with all the exact values and then filters for it. There are many techniques to do exactly what you want, but you need a database to store all exact values before mapping.